# My functions keep being "not defined"

Tags: javascript

I am making a periodic table. you can see the whole thing here: [My periodic table](http://tinyurl.com/ptable-html)

(Not done yet, i know 89-103 is not correct! And that actinoids are not in the table yet)

It seems like everytime i change something in my script, all the functions are suddenly "undefined" (even though i only change one).

I have an example here:

This code works:

```js
function alkali() {
   var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
 while(++i < colslen){
  if(cols[i].className.indexOf("alkali")>0){}
  else {cols[i].style.opacity = "0.3"}
 }
}
function alkaline() {
   var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
 while(++i < colslen){
  if(cols[i].className.indexOf("alKaline")>0){}
  else {cols[i].style.opacity = "0.3"}
 }
}

function lanthanoid() {
   var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
 while(++i < colslen){
  if(cols[i].className.indexOf("lanthanoid")>0){}
  else {cols[i].style.opacity = "0.3"}
 }
}

function actinoids() {
   var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
 while(++i < colslen){
  if(cols[i].className.indexOf("actinoids")>0){}
  else {cols[i].style.opacity = "0.3"}
 }
}

function transitionMetal() {
   var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
 while(++i < colslen){
  if(cols[i].className.indexOf("transitionMetal")>0){}
  else {cols[i].style.opacity = "0.3"}
 }
}

function poormetal() {
   var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
 while(++i < colslen){
  if(cols[i].className.indexOf("poormetal")>0){}
  else {cols[i].style.opacity = "0.3"}
 }
}

function nonmetal() {
   var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
 while(++i < colslen){
  if(cols[i].className.indexOf("nonmetal")>0){}
  else {cols[i].style.opacity = "0.3"}
 }
}

function noblegas() {
   var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
 while(++i < colslen){
  if(cols[i].className.indexOf("noblegas")>0){}
  else {cols[i].style.opacity = "0.3"}
 }
}

function reset() {
   var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
    while(++i < colslen){
        cols[i].style.opacity = "1";
 }
}
```

```html
        <td class="alkali I" onmouseover="alkali()" onmouseout="reset()">Alkali Metals</td>
        <td class="alKaline I" onmouseover="alkaline()" onmouseout="reset()">Alkaline Metals</td>
        <td class="lanthanoid I" onmouseover="lanthanoid()" onmouseout="reset()">Lantha-<br>noids</td>
        <td class="actinoids I" onmouseover="actinoids()" onmouseout="reset()">Actinoids</td>
        <td class="transitionMetal I" onmouseover="transitionMetal()" onmouseout="reset()">Transition Metals</td>
        <td class="poormetal I" onmouseover="poormetal()" onmouseout="reset()">Poor Metals</td>
        <td class="nonmetal I" onmouseover="nonmetal()" onmouseout="reset()">Non-<br>metals</td>
        <td class="noblegas I" onmouseover="noblegas()" onmouseout="reset()">Noble gases</td>
```

(The code above is currently on the linked site)

I relized there was an easier way of doing this, since all the functions do kind of the same thing. However, when i changed the code all functions are "undefined". Even the reset function which i have not touched!

```js
function populate(catagory) {
   var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
 while(++i < colslen){
  if(cols[i].className.indexOf(catagory)>0){}
  else {cols[i].style.opacity = "0.3"}
 }
}

function reset() {
   var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
    while(++i < colslen){
        cols[i].style.opacity = "1";
 }
}
```

```html
        <td class="alkali I" onmouseover="populate('alkali')" onmouseout="reset()">Alkali Metals</td>
        <td class="alKaline I" onmouseover="populate('alkaline')" onmouseout="reset()">Alkaline Metals</td>
        <td class="lanthanoid I" onmouseover="populate('lanthanoid')" onmouseout="reset()">Lantha-<br>noids</td>
        <td class="actinoids I" onmouseover="populate('actinoids')" onmouseout="reset()">Actinoids</td>
        <td class="transitionMetal I" onmouseover="populate('transitionMetal')" onmouseout="reset()">Transition Metals</td>
        <td class="poormetal I" onmouseover="populate('poormetal')" onmouseout="reset()">Poor Metals</td>
        <td class="nonmetal I" onmouseover="populate('nonmetal')" onmouseout="reset()">Non-<br>metals</td>
        <td class="noblegas I" onmouseover="populate('noblegas')" onmouseout="reset()">Noble gases</td>
```

I have had alot of issues like this, which makes me think that i am missing somthing obvius.

Does anyone help me point out the issue here?

Comment: any other error in your browser console....

Comment: do you have  a demo where the issue is recreated

Comment: NVM while writing this post i had to rewrite some of the code i had deleted again. And then i worked like it was supposed to do! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given us a lot to work with, but the only reasons I can see for `populate` and `reset` to suddenly be undefined are:

1. If you put them inside a scoping function or `onload` callback or similar, so they're no longer global. `onXyz` attribute event handler functions must be globals. (One of many reasons not to use them.)
2. You introduce a syntax error when editing (you've said this has happened "many times" so I think this is the more likely issue). If so, you can see the syntax error in the web console when you open your page, just be sure you're showing the web console: To open the devtools on most browsers, press Ctrl+Shift+I or Cmd+Shift+I or F12.

---

Side note: You might want to look at the `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` functions, which would simplify your DOM queries a bit. They accept any CSS selector. The "all" version returns a list, the other one returns the first match.

So for instance this:

```
var cols = document.getElementById('theTable').getElementsByTagName('td'), // ...
```

becomes:

```
var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#theTable td'), // ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I am very new to this whole web development thing (started last month). I will try to use the querySelectorAll as you say.